# download files using regular expression in R language

Tags: regex, r

Is there a package or function in R which can download files and support regular expression like wget in linux?

I just want to download some cel files from GEO. But some file ended with cel.gz, others ended with CEL.gz. What I have is the GSM ID, such as GSM107523. I'd want to a function can download a file with the name GSM107523.cel.gz or GSM107523.CEL.gz. Gererally, I use `download.file` to download files.

For example:
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/samples/GSM107nnn/GSM107523/suppl/GSM107523.cel.gz
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/samples/GSM153nnn/GSM153499/suppl/GSM153499.CEL.gz

Comment: I didn't realize that this was a genome site before I posted my answer.  You'll going to want to look into the BioConductor package and BioQuery

Comment: @RichardScriven No, I need download these GSM file directly. GEOquery::getGEO cannot make it.

Comment: I've made an edit.  Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some snooping around on http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/, I came to the conclusion that downloading the files via `http` would be much faster. Here's what I came up with.

`getGSMFile()` will, for all strings in the given `x`, either return the file paths or download the files.  You can set the option with `download`.  If  you set `http = FALSE`, it will try to download the `ftp`.  But keep in mind that this failed for me on several attempts.

```
getGSMFile <- function (x, download = TRUE, http = TRUE, destfile, ...) 
{
    urlRoot <- "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov"
    query <- sprintf("/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=%s&targ=self&view=full&form=html", 
        x)
    fullPath <- paste0(urlRoot, query)
    linkList <- vapply(fullPath, function(x) {
        links <- getHTMLLinks(x, 
            xpQuery = "//a/@href[contains(., 'cel') or contains(., 'CEL')]")
       ftp <- grepl("ftp", links, fixed = TRUE)
       URLdecode(if(http) paste0(urlRoot, links[!ftp]) else links[ftp])
    }, character(1L), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    if (!download) return(linkList)
    for (link in linkList) download.file(link, destfile = destfile, ...)
}
```

And here are the test runs on your two GSMs

```
x <- c("GSM107523", "GSM153499")
getGSMFile(x, download = FALSE)
# [1] "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSM107523&format=file&file=GSM107523.cel.gz"
# [2] "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSM153499&format=file&file=GSM153499.CEL.gz"

tmp <- tempfile()
getGSMFile(x, destfile = tmp)
# trying URL 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSM107523&format=file&file=GSM107523.cel.gz'
# Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 3960200 bytes (3.8 Mb)
# opened URL
# ==================================================
#     downloaded 3.8 Mb
# 
# trying URL 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSM153499&format=file&file=GSM153499.CEL.gz'
# Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 3208938 bytes (3.1 Mb)
# opened URL
# ==================================================
#     downloaded 3.1 Mb
```

Comment: `url.exists` is a method to cope with it. Is there a way to like `wget www.xxxx.*.gz` in R (* will represents cel or CEL)? Thank you.

Comment: I've made a slight edit. Function `getHTMLLinks` is from XML and make destfile of download.file wisely. Are there any words in http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ concerning the speed of http and ftp? It just seems to be easier to implement the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use grepl. Given a vector of strings, it'll return TRUE if the string matches the regular expression and FALSE otherwise.

```
vector_strings <- c("a.cel.gz", "a.CEL.gz", "a.txt")
grepl("[cel|CEL].gz$", vector_strings)
```

Comment: How to download it? because I donot know what is the suffix of  file.